# Como utilizar o método TimesTamp().dayofweek em um dataframe?

Tags: python, data, pandas, dataframe

Comecei a estudar python a pouco tempo e surgiu um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.Tenho um arquivo csv contendo duas colunas('ds' = datas e 'y'= dado de um resultado qualquer da respectiva data), nesse arquivo eu preciso agrupar todas as datas por dias da semana para conseguir fazer as minhas analises futuramente. Porém não consigo descobrir um jeito para manipular o data frame de forma que possa realizar isso.
Aqui está o código teste que eu tentei fazer.

O arquivo csv que estou tentando manipular:
https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/example.csv',delimiter=',') #Lê o arquivo
df[pd.Timestamp(df['ds']).dayofweek]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para definir o dia da semana você pode usar:

`pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).dt.dayofweek`

Se quiser agrupar todas as datas em uma lista por dia você pode usar :

`df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).dt.dayofweek).ds.apply(list)`

Se for a soma de y:

`df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).dt.dayofweek).y.sum()`